# accessing subItem of a Tree in SWT Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tree, swt

I have used Tree to display all the data. I have expanded the data having the same LoanId with different IssueAmount . My output is as shown in the Image.
In the Image the row containing S.No. 3 is the parentItem and the one below it in yellow color is it's subItem.
I can access the Parent Items. Suppose i want to access the third column of third row, I can acess it  using the code as follows:

```
TreeItem Item[] = tree.getItems();
System.out.println("The Item is"+Item[2].getText(2));
```

Similarly i want to have access to the subItems(the ones highlighted in yellow). How can i have access to the subItems . Thank You..[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`TreeItem`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TreeItem.html).`getItems()`. Note that sub items are only available if the parent node has been expanded at least once.

```
TreeItem items[] = tree.getItems();
//Print all items recursively
printItems(items);
...
void printItems(TreeItem items[]) {
    for (TreeItem i: items) {
        System.out.println(i.getText(2));
        //Check if expanded
        if (!i.getExpanded())
            continue;
        printItems(i.getItems());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the code , but i want the subItems to be Printed only if their parents are expanded, the above code prints all the subItems of a parent even if they are not expanded.